# How do I find the points of intersection of cosx and sin2x?

Tags: calculus

SO I am trying to figure out the points of intersection from the interval **0 to pi/2** and mathematically, I set both equations equal to one another and solved for x.

I did $$\cos x = \sin 2x$$ and then got $$1/2 = \sin x$$ which gave me $$\pi/6$$
This is not completely right, since in the book, it says there are two points of inter\section and the one I am missing is $$\pi/2.$$ How do I get that point without graphing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General solution**:

This will work for $\cos ax=\sin bx$ for real $a,b$

$$\cos x=\sin2x=\cos\left(\frac\pi2-2x\right)$$

$$\implies x=2m\pi\pm\left(\frac\pi2-2x\right)$$ where $m$ is any integer

Consider '+','-' one by one and find suitable $m$ such $0<x<\dfrac\pi2$

---

Alternatively, $\sin2x=\cos x=\sin\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)$

$$\implies2x=n\pi+(-1)^n\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)$$ where $n$ is any integer

Consider even $n=2r$(say) an odd $n=2r+1$(say) one by one

Answer (score 1):

$\cos x=\sin 2x\quad \Rightarrow\quad \cos x=2\cos x\sin x\quad \cos x(1-2\sin x)=0$
Hence there is also posibility $\cos x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve this equation is use the fact that 
$\sin (2x) = 2 \sin x \cos x$ 
so we get 
$2 \sin x \cos x = \cos x$ 
One solution is when 
$\cos x = 0$ 
 and the other is when 
$\sin x = 1/2$ 
so we get 
$ x = pi/2$ for $\cos x = 0$ and 
$ x = pi/6 $ for $\sin x = 1/2$